# Working with classes and lists

Tags: vb.net, class, types

I am trying to declare type Product and type Productlist
can anyone tell me if this is right way to do it ?

```
Public Class Product
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property price As Double
End Class
Public Class ProductsList
  Public Property items() As New List(Of Product)
End Class
```

I mean can I just write

```
Public Class Product
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property price As Double
End Class

Public property ProductsList as new List(Of Product)
```

instead ?

Comment: Tag your question with the relevant language, so people can find it more easily to answer it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach seems like better practice. You would code with it like this:

```
Dim p as new Product()
p.name = "Apple"
p.price = 1

Dim pList as new ProductList()
pList.Items.Add(p)
```

The issue with the second approach is you would have a wrapper class, eg DemoWrapper:

```
Public Class DemoWrapper

   Public Class Product
      Public Property name As String
      Public Property price As Double
    End Class

    Public ProductsList as new List(Of Product)

End Class
```

Your code would end up like this:

```
Dim p as new DemoWrapper.Product()
```